# Get the id of html page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an id on my page from that I have taken all the html by using `.html()` function in a variable .Now, I want to use the id from the variable in which I have stored the html. How can I do this in jQuery? I am not getting any idea. Please help me in this!

```
var idhtml= $("#id").html();
```

Like this, I have the html in idhtml

```
<input type="text" id="id1" name="id1" value="" class ="test" />
<input type="text" id="id2" name="id1" value="" class ="test" />
<input type="text" id="id3" name="id1" value="" class ="test" />
```

By `idhtml`, I want to get the id in the variable.

Comment: Err, what ???????

Comment: @adeneo i am not getting error how i can acess these id's .Please let me know

Comment: @GauravPandey: which ids you want and where??

Comment: you want to access value of textbox??

Comment: actuall i want to set attr on the ids

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IDs like this:

```
$("input[id^='id']").each(function () { 
    console.log(this.id); 

    // Change the id:
    $(this).attr("id", "new_id");
});
```

Select every `input` with an id that starts with `id` and for each input returned, print its ID in the console.

Comment: $("input[id^='id']").each(function () { 
    $(this).attr('readonly',true);
   });

Comment: Try: `$(this).prop('readonly', true);`. If it doesn't work, then it is something else. Make sure the selector returns the inputs.

Comment: in the console it is printing the input type html

Comment: this in the console <input type="text" id="id1" name="id1" value="" class ="test" />

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()`.

To set the attribute you can use

1) `.attr('attribute_name','attribute_value')` or

2) `.data('attribute_name','attribute_value')`

with appropriate selector.

```
 $("[name='id1']").each(function () { 
     console.log($(this).attr(id));
     //to set the attr you can use
     $(this).attr('attribute_name','attribute_value');
     //to set custom attribute, use .data()
     $(this).data('attribute_name','attribute_value');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var formId = $('form').attr('youId');
    });
```